# Unbiased estimator of $1/(1-a)$ when random variables are Poisson(a)

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, estimation

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be Poisson with parameter $a$. I am looking for a unbiased estimator of $h(a)=\frac{1}{1-a}$

Let  $T$ be a statistic and $g(t)$ be it's pmf. Then if we have $E(T)= h(a)$ then $T$ is unbiased for $h$.
So we must have

$$\frac{e^a}{1-a}= \sum _k \frac{g(k)a^k}{k!} $$

If $ 0<a<1 $ we can expand left hand side and get the values of $ g(k) $ by equating corresponding coefficients. But in this case I'm not able to get the estimator. I am also having difficulty to figure out what to do if $ a>1 $

Any help is appreciated ☺️

Comment: @anyone Is this question suitable for here or do I have to ask in cross validated?

Comment: @quanum_spin I think it's fine here. Welcome to Math.SE!

Comment: Multiply both sides on $1-a$, expand exponent in l.h.s. and equate coefficients as well.

Comment: Look also at https://oeis.org/A002627 after equating coefficients

Comment: @NCh That's really helpful! Can you give some hint to find corresponding estimator?

Comment: The question is duplicated in https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/553383/7224

Comment: @quantum_spin Use some formula from oeis - say, $$X!\cdot \sum\limits_{k=0}^X\dfrac{1}{k!}$$ - for $a<1$. What to do with the case $a>1$ I do not know: the expectation diverges.